# useref() scrollIntoView() scrolling page instead of the div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref, js-scrollintoview

I am trying to scroll to latest message in my chat component.. but when i send a message, useref() scrolls complete page and chatbox too. is there any way to scroll only a selected div.

[behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pouBu.gif)

```
useEffect(() => {
    scrollRef.current?.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
}, [messages]);
```

This is my loop:

```
messages.map((m) => {
    return(
        <div ref={scrollRef} key={m._id}>
           <Message />
        </div>
     );
})
```

I'm trying to scroll only chatbox not the whole page.

Comment: [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) options defaults to `{block: "start", inline: "nearest"}`, so the browser will scroll all scrollable ancestors to bring the target element to the top. You could see if specifying `{block:"nearest"}` is suitable for your needs; anything more sophisticated might require a custom scrolling solution.